# MySQL date-time-zone input

Tags: mysql, date, time, formatting, timezone

I'm not overly familiar with dates and times formats in MySQL, and I've tried looking here on stackoverflow for solutions, but cannot find anything which specifically answers my query...

I have the following MySQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE friends_details (name VARCHAR(255), last_contact DATETIME);

INSERT INTO friends_details VALUES
('Bob', '2018-09-06 04:23:51 BST');

INSERT INTO friends_details VALUES
('Eszter', '2018-01-21 17:24:06 CET');

INSERT INTO friends_details VALUES
('Sue', '2018-09-01 11:18:21 EDT');

INSERT INTO friends_details VALUES
('Jack', '2018-02-27 23:11:47 UTC');
```

I get a failure because the format of values I'm trying to input into the **last_contact** fields does not match the format as specified in the first line of code where the table **friends_details** is created.

Is there any way I can specifically input the timezone 3 letter code details of the `last_contact` fields, and get them accepted by MySQL ?

So if I specify `SELECT * FROM friends_details;` later on, I would like to be able to get the following output:

```
Bob,    2018-09-06 04:23:51 BST
Eszter, 2018-01-21 17:24:06 CET
Sue,    2018-09-01 11:18:21 EDT
Jack,   2018-02-27 23:11:47 UTC
```

I do not want any of times converted to UTC in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to Create one more column to store the timezone separately:

```
CREATE TABLE friends_details (name VARCHAR(255), 
                              last_contact DATETIME, 
                              timezone VARCHAR(3));

INSERT INTO friends_details VALUES
('Bob', '2018-09-06 04:23:51', 'BST');

INSERT INTO friends_details VALUES
('Eszter', '2018-01-21 17:24:06', 'CET');

INSERT INTO friends_details VALUES
('Sue', '2018-09-01 11:18:21', 'EDT');

INSERT INTO friends_details VALUES
('Jack', '2018-02-27 23:11:47', 'UTC');
```

**Note** that in your application code (eg: PHP), you can do string operations on the datetime (with timezone) and extract timezone out separately, for `Insert` query.

---

However, general practice is to store the time in UTC, and in the second column, store the actual timezone's gap with UTC (in terms of hours).

Eg:

```
CREATE TABLE friends_details (name VARCHAR(255), 
                              last_contact_utc DATETIME, 
                              timezone_gap decimal(5,2));

-- CET is UTC + 1, so the time in UTC will be CET - 1
INSERT INTO friends_details VALUES
('Eszter', '2018-01-21 16:24:06', 1);

-- EDT is UTC - 4, so the time in UTC will be EDT + 4
INSERT INTO friends_details VALUES
('Sue', '2018-09-01 15:18:21', -4);

INSERT INTO friends_details VALUES
('Jack', '2018-02-27 23:11:47', 0);
```

Now, doing operations to calculate datetime differences become simpler, without worrying about the timezone gap(s). For display, you can simply get both the columns, and change it to relevant timezone accordingly.

Comment: Hi @madhur-bhaiya,

Comment: Hi @madhur-bhaiya, Is it possible to do time calculations using the separate columns you have specified in your code? Perhaps I was not clear in my original question, but what I would like is to be able to do a time calculation using the date, time and zone info given in the table, without having to do any manual conversion of all the rows to one time zone. So for example, if I want to get the difference in time between Bob and Sue, MySQL should calculate that using only '2018-09-06 04:23:51 BST' and '2018-09-01 11:18:21 EDT'. Hence the need for MySQL to accept the fields as I have specified.

Comment: @SSB please check the updated answer. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Hi @madhur-bhaiya, Thank You for your answer. I was hoping that I could get MySQL to accept the timezone code directly. I'll use your suggestion if that is the only way of specifying a timezone.

Comment: @SSB I am not saying that it is the only way. But it is a generally acceptable practice and convenient as well. If this answer helps you, kindly mark it accepted answer (green check), and optionally upvote too. Thanks :)